# Laravel counted price issue

Tags: php, laravel, calculator, price, calculation

i'm working in laravel but really some help. I'm trying to find the price of a discounted produkt.

'totalPrice' => 1 - $request->input('discount')*$request->input('price'),

( 0.2 is discount value from table )

Right now it says    1 - 0.2 * price

I want it to be      1 - 0.2 * price = 0.8 * price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the [PEMDAS](http://www.mathmeeting.com/PEMDAS/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAr93gBRDSARIsADvHiOqRBAgv7qbJg7RRx5IaBLGV1LuiT6oH8Bwp0yxyBl0xBdpB-hMitnMaAvtjEALw_wcB) Rules,

wherein you need to include `()` Parentheses in the `( 1 - $request->input('discount') )` and then multiply its result.

Just like this.

```
'totalPrice' => ( 1 - $request->input('discount') ) * $request->input('price')
```

In this equation the system will substract first and then multiply its result.

Comment: All of us once became idiot, but keep coding makes you great! godbless!